# [Buoyancy Plugin] Possible bug

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm using Gazebo  6.6.0 with Ubuntu 14.04 and currently I'm experiencing strange behaviors with the buoyancy plugin shipped with this version.

The following minimal working example shows two sphere, of mass 1 kg, and the usage of the buoyancy plugin where I force the volume of these two sphere to be equal to their mass. Having fluid density equal to 1 should result having the two objects floating in the air, because in this case force_of_gravity == force_of_buoyancy.
Unfortunately only the first sphere, l1, floats whereas the second one falls down.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.5'>
<model name="buoyancy_example">

  <!-- ================== link l1 ================== -->
  <link name="l1">

    <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>

    <inertial> <mass>1</mass> </inertial>

    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
          <sphere> <radius>0.5</radius> </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
          <sphere> <radius>0.5</radius> </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

  </link>

  <!-- ================== link l2 ================== -->
  <link name="l2">

    <pose>2 0 1 0 0 0</pose>

    <inertial> <mass>1</mass> </inertial>

    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
          <sphere> <radius>0.5</radius> </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
          <sphere> <radius>0.5</radius> </sphere>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

  </link>

  <!-- ================== buoyancy plugin ================== -->
  <plugin name="buoyancy" filename="libBuoyancyPlugin.so">

    <fluid_density>1</fluid_density>

    <link name="l1">
      <center_of_volume>0 0 0</center_of_volume>
      <volume>1</volume> <!-- volume == mass ==> object should float -->
    </link>

    <link name="l2">
      <center_of_volume>0 0 0</center_of_volume>
      <volume>1</volume> <!-- volume == mass ==> object should float -->
    </link>

  </plugin>

</model>
</sdf>
```

[image: image description]

Based on my trials I believe that the problem is in this for statement [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/206d5e2d67a1eba2a53875b86dfac205070bd2dc/plugins/BuoyancyPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#BuoyancyPlugin.cc-56), which doesn't return the next link element within the plugin tag. Does anyone know how I can fix this bug and be able to use multiple "links" tags within this plugin?

Thanks,

Marco.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13756/%5Bbuoyancy-plugin%5D-possible-bug/) by [Marco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2483/marco/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like a bug. That statement you mentioned should be:

`linkElem = linkElem->GetNextElement("link")`

It would be great if you could make a pull request to Gazebo with the fix, and a bonus if you add a test with your use case. The pull request could be targeted at branch `gazebo6`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2483/marco/) on 2016-06-29**:
Hi,

I just checked your suggest and now the plugin works ... thanks :)
I'll make the pull request, but I'm not totally sure about how to write a test for it ... could you give me more information about how to do it?
Thanks

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-29**:
Oh I wouldn't worry too much about the test, it would just be a bonus ;) It would probably involve writing an integration test: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/test/integration/

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2483/marco/) on 2016-06-30**:
ok, I created a pull request targeted to gazebo6. About the test: I'm not totally sure about how to check if the plugin is working well. Should I spawn two objects and check if the heights of their centers of gravity are > 0 ?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-30**:
Thanks! Sounds good. Make sure to let enough iterations pass so the models have time to float.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-30**:
The pull request with the fix has been merged by the way ;) You're still welcome to add a test, it will make sure we don't break this in the future by mistake.

**Comment by [Marco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2483/marco/) on 2016-07-01**:
cool! I'll try to write a simple test in the next days ;)